# Consulta bases de datos en ruby on rails

Tags: base-de-datos, ruby-on-rails

estoy tratando de aprender rails, y el tema de las bases de datos se me ha hecho un tanto dificil entenderlo.
Cree una base de datos por consola y posterior migracion, este se supone que crea 3 bases de datos(dev,test y producción).
Pero al ver el servidor de bd desde un administrador de bases de datos(ejem: myqlworkbench) no aparece ninguna de esas bases de datos creadas.
Hay alguna forma de poder administrarlas en modo grafico o son solo bases de datos "virtuales"?

Comment: Oye amigo, aqui te dejo un Curso Gratuito para que aprendas un poco mas del tema, puede encuentres lo que buscas exactamente, talvez no conteste tu pregunta como dices, pero una de tus dudas era que estabas tratando de aprender, asi que si, te he dado una respuesta. https://codigofacilito.com/cursos/rails3

Comment: que es exactamente lo que tiene tus migraciones?

Comment: se crearon las 3 bases de datos mencionadas en el archivo database, pero no son visibles desde ningun cliente de bases de datos. Solo puedo manejarlas por la consola rails

Comment: como compruebas que se crearon?. Tienes que tener claro que configurar los parámetros en el archivo `database.yml` solo configura rails para que se conecte a dichabase de datos, no es que crees esa base de datos; por lo que tu eres el que tiene que crear la base de datos y darle los permisos necesarios al usuario que utilizaras con rails.

Comment: ah ok, eso no sabia. Pero la aplicacion funciona conectada a la base de datos con el nombre que le di y puedo hacer operaciones crud que supongo que es a mysql, porque elimine la gema sqlite

Comment: ¿Y mysql workbench te tira algún error o mensaje? ¿Estás seguro que son los mismos datos de conexión que pusiste en tu archivo `config/database.yml`? ¿Has probado de conectarte a la BD con otro cliente que no sea mysql workbench? quizás usar SQuirreL SQL, o la misma línea de comandos de mysql con `mysql -h tuhost -u tuusuario tubasededatos -p`. PD: para contestar a un comentario en tu propia pregunta, debes agregar un arroba como en @daniel.- para que la otra persona sepa que contestaste.

Comment: si,los datos estan bien,tambien intente desde navicat. Cuado listo las bases de datos en la consola de mysql si aparecen las 3 que se crearon, eso es lo extraño

Answer (score 1):

Cuando creas por defecto una primera aplicación rails, esta configurada para usar sqlite como base de datos por lo que al ejecutar `rake db:create` y `rake db:migrate` estas creando nuevas bases de datos en este gestor de bd, para explorarlos podrias usar alguna herramienta de cliente de sqlite y abrir los archivos alojados en la carpeta /db de tu proyecto.

Comment: yo cree mi app con mysql usando: rails new appname -d mysql

Comment: En ese caso, las bases de datos son físicas y deberían estar visibles desde workbench, debes verificar que la conexión que hiciste es correcta, tienes una única instalación de mysql y el usuario de conexión es el mismo.

Comment: ya lo verifique ,la aplicacion funciona con datos , mysql esta bien instalado

Answer (score 1):

Una vez que creas una migracion, debes correr en la consola:

```
rake db:create
```

y luego

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: amigo hice eso y sigo igual sin verlas

Comment: Puedes publicar el contenido de tu archivo database.yml?

Comment: Y si la consola te devuelve algún mensaje al correr esos rake commands postealos

Comment: no nada, todo sale bien

Answer (score 1):

Por defecto rails utiliza **sqlite** y por defecto cuando ejecutas comandos de rails los corre en entorno **development** asi que una vez que corras `rake db:create` y `rake db:migrate` obtendras **una** base de datos sqlite **real** en el directorio `/db` generalmente con el nombre `development.sqlite3` o similar. Para administrarla graficamente puedes utilizar [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Tambien puedes configurar MySQL o PostgreSQL para lo cual tienes que editar el archivo `database.yml` con los datos de las bases de datos y en tu server esos datos deben de coincidir.

Answer (score 0):

hola entiendo lo que pides exactamente tendrías que cambiarte a my sql y localhost por default del mysql.. con otra base de datos no se. te recomiendos que uses este comando en la consola `rails g scaffold nombre_tabla_campo1:string  campo2:integer  campo3:integer` ya que este te genera El CRUD. agregar modificar actualizar y destruir. aparte de los controladores y las vistas solo tendrías que ejecutar eso y se te facilitaría un poco el aprendizaje..